# Code coverage for lines following methods that always throw exceptions

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I understand that 100% code coverage is just a goal to shoot for, but it's annoying to have a line containing a closing brace counted as *not covered* because it follows a method call whose sole purpose is to throw an exception. Here's a simple example from my base test case class to demonstrate:

```
function checkForSkipAllTests() {
    if (self::$_skipAllTests) {
        self::markTestSkipped();   // [1] always throws an exception
    }                              // [2] shown as executable but not covered
}
```

Since [1] always exits the method, line [2] is not actually reachable. Is there any way to tell Xdebug this **by annotating the `markTestSkipped()` method itself?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [pull request](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/pull/77) got merged so starting with php-code-coverage 1.1.2, which should come around rather soon (with PHPUnit 3.6.3 or 3.6.4) one will be able to write:

```
private static function checkForSkipAllTests() {
    if (self::$_skipAllTests) {
        self::markTestSkipped();
    } // @codeCoverageIgnore
}
```

Also in the further away future when xDebug will be able to provide 'Conditionals' coverage i think i remember discussion about making the whole issue going away with that refactoring as the closing brace will just count as 'covered' when the last statement in a function terminates the function... But I might be wrong on that

Comment: That was quick! Indeed, this is precisely why I submitted the request. It's good to hear that Xdebug is looking to solve the problem at the source. Conditionals coverage would be very cool, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can surround the line with stard/end comments to have PHP_CodeCoverage ignore it, but that means doing it everywhere the method is called.

```
function checkForSkipAllTests() {
    if (self::$_skipAllTests) {
        self::markTestSkipped();
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    }
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
}
```

This is a maintenance nightmare and prone to error. I would really like to avoid this solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that 100% code coverage is just a goal to shoot for, but it's annoying to have a line containing a closing brace counted as not covered because it follows a method call whose sole purpose is to throw an exception. Here's a simple example from my base test case class to demonstrate:

Indeed, 100% code coverage is not a goal, but it's nice to have, especially if it takes you zero time to make it so. I do wonder though; your tests are not the files that are to be tested. I *never* test my tests, nor am I interested in their code coverage. I already know which tests are done, which succeeded, which failed and which are skipped. This is what PHPUnit brings to the table for me; `.....S...F` is enough feedback.

My tests are in a separate directory, which isn't included in code coverage; it just seems useless to do so, in my eyes. Anyway, if you're sold on having code coverage reports on your testcases, you might want to simply get rid of the `}`, like so:

```
function checkForSkipAllTests() {
    if (self::$_skipAllTests)
        self::markTestSkipped();
}
```

Yeah, I know that having an `if` without curly brackets will make me the least cool person answering your question, but it seems like a much easier solution than having some annotations which magically work.

Comment: If unclebob is allowed to use ifs without braces we are too :) --- I just assumed this was a test helper class and those usually get tested (as they are not tests them selfs they need tests). Good thing to note still, I've overlooked that

Comment: @edorian LOL at the Uncle Bob remark. Still, it's one of the few stances he makes I usually disagree on. Maybe that's just my far more limited experience speaking though. :)

Comment: @Berry - As edorian said, these classes are in our testing framework, the base test case that subclasses `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and is used by all our actual tests. I certainly don't track code coverage on the unit tests themselves. :)

Comment: @Berry - Omitting the enclosing braces would work here but not in multi-line blocks. And like you, I abhor blocks without braces.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Obviously, it wouldn't work for multiline blocks. But then; your example displays a single line ;)